# Telerik RadTextBox becomes readonly after selecting a Chrome AutoFill option

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, telerik, autofill

Wondering if anybody has seen this issue before or fixed it:

When the form loads, I can manually type into my address field (all fields are RadTextBox) with no issues

If I start filling the form from the top, after I enter the first few characters of my email address - Chrome provides a list of email addreses for me to choose from, If I select one - it fills in the rest of the form with the information associated with that email address.

So far so good.

When I now try to edit the subsequent fields, I cannot - they have become readonly!!!

In trying to solve this, my instinct is to open Chrome developer tools to see the difference between the fields that work, and those that don't.

But lo and behold - as soon as I open developer tools - the problem goes away!

Any ideas?

Comment: Disabling the browser's default stylesheet also solves the problem. I assume that I could override whatever is in the user-agent stylesheet that is causing the problem... But where to begin! As soon as I try to see what spurious style Chrome has added, using developer tools - the feature of developer tools that highlights the element current element in the window, obviously changes the styling , fixes the problem and overwrites the troublesome style rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Thanks to Stefan Sedich!!!

http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/11/04/bug-with-latest-google-chrome-and-asp-net-validation.aspx